For which $p$ does $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin (x^2)}{1+x^p+\ln(\arctan(x))}$ converge?
I have absolutely no idea how to determine p for which
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin (x^2)}{1+x^p+\ln(\arctan(x))} \,dx$$
converges.
It looks similar to the Fresnel integral
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty} \sin (x^2)\,dx$$
But how can I finally solve it?

Welcome to MSE! See the MathJax tutorial to acquaint yourself with writing math on this site.

You may wish to consider the integral of the function $1/(x^{1+\epsilon}+1)$. This can give you a range of $p$ where the integral converges.

How do you prove the Fresnel integral converges? Can you pursue that same approach?

We establish the following lemma:

Lemma. Suppose $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f : [a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, monotone, and bounded. Then
$$ \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \sin(x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x $$
converges.
Proof. This is essentially a corollary of the Dirichlet test. Let $S(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \sin(t^2) \, \mathrm{d}t$. We know that $S(x)$ is bounded and $S(x)$ converges as $x \to \infty$ or as $x \to -\infty$. This also implies that $S(x)$ is bounded on all of $\mathbb{R}$ by some constant $C > 0$.
Now, by integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \sin(x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= [f(x) S(x)]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b} S(x) f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= f(b)S(b) - f(a)S(a) - \int_{a}^{b} S(x) f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is monotone and bounded, $f(b)$ converges as $b\to\infty$, hence the same is true for $f(b)S(b)$. Moreover,
$$\int_{a}^{b} |S(x)f'(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq C \int_{a}^{b} |f'(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x
= C|f(b) - f(a)| $$
by the monotonicity of $f$. Since this is further bounded by an absolute constant, we conclude that $\int_{a}^{\infty} S(x)f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ converges absolutely and the desired claim follows. $\square$

Now here is a hint based on this lemma: Check that $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^p + \log(\arctan x)}$ is eventually monotone for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

As I found, $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^p +ln(arctan(x))}$ isn't monotone, at least for p < -1.
It's derivative has roots larger than 1 for p < -1 and it follows from this that I can't use lemma for p < -1. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere in my reasoning?

@Dmitro, $f(x)$ doesn't have to be monotone on all of $x \geq 1$. It just need to be monotone on $x \geq a$ for some $a$. The reason is that you can always split the integral into two parts:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(x^2),\mathrm{d}x=\int_{1}^{a}f(x)\sin(x^2),\mathrm{d}x+\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(x^2),\mathrm{d}x$$
and the convergence is only affected by the second term. (That is why I used the term 'eventually monotone'.) For example, $f(x)$ for $p=-2$ is monotone decreasing for $x\geq a$ with $a\approx 2.76776$.
